# How can I get a list of repositories in the view model before the table view is refreshed?

Tags: swift, multithreading, mvvm, grand-central-dispatch, moya

I'm trying to build an app that searches GitHub repositories. And I'm using MVVM and Moya. When I call a method to search I get table view reloaded before a server responds.

So the app flow should be: 
A user types in a search query into the search bar. In `searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_:)` of `SearchViewController` called my method to search. The method is inside `SearchViewModel`. So view model's method triggers `RepositoryService` and then `NetworkService`.

I put some print statements to see an order of execution. And in the console, I got: `2 3 4 (Here the table view is refreshing) 1`. I've tried to use GCD in different places, also I tried to use barriers. At the end of the day, the table view is still refreshing before `print(1)` is called.

**SearchViewController:**

```
extension SearchViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        guard let query = searchBar.text, query.count > 2 else { return }
        viewModel.searchRepositories(withQuery: query) { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            print(4)
            print("Reloading...")
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

**SearchViewModel:**

```
var repositories = [Repository]()

func searchRepositories(withQuery query: String, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    repositories = repositoryService.searchRepositories(withQuery: query)
    print(3)
    completion()
}
```

**RepositoryService:**

```
private var repositories = [Repository]()

func searchRepositories(withQuery query: String) -> [Repository] {
    networkService?.searchRepositories(withQuery: query) { [weak self] repositories in
        guard let self = self, let repositories = repositories else { return }
        self.repositories += repositories
    }
    print(2)
    return self.repositories
}
```

**NetworkService:**

```
func searchRepositories(withQuery query: String,
                        completionHandler: @escaping (([Repository]?) -> Void)) {
    provider?.request(.searchRepo(query: query)) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let response):
            do {
                let repositories = try response.map(SearchResults<Repository>.self)
                print(1)
                completionHandler(repositories.items)
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is basically that you are not handling async requests properly.

Consider the code:

```
var repositories = [Repository]()

func searchRepositories(withQuery query: String, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    repositories = repositoryService.searchRepositories(withQuery: query) // here we are going to create a network request in the background, which takes time. 
    print(3)
    completion() // when you call this, your network request is still trying, so when your tableView refreshes... the data hasn't returned yet. 
}
```

As you can see in the comments, what will happen here is:

- call to network
- print(3)
- completion -> reload Table View
- network responses with data -> you do nothing.

What you should be doing...

```
func searchRepositories(withQuery query: String, completion: @escaping (SomeResponseType?, Error?) -> Void) {
    repositories = repositoryService.searchRepositories(withQuery: query) { response in 
         completion(results, error)
    }
}
```

You have followed this pattern elsewhere but you need to cover all async requests.

Same here:

```
func searchRepositories(withQuery query: String) -> [Repository] {
    networkService?.searchRepositories(withQuery: query) { [weak self] repositories in
        guard let self = self, let repositories = repositories else { return }
        self.repositories += repositories
    }
    print(2)
    return self.repositories
}
```

`return self.repositories` will be called instantly after the network call starts and the network request would not of had time to return the data.

Couple of useful resources on the topic:

- [Grand central dispatch in Swift 4 - RW](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5370-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-1-2)
- [URLSession tutorial - RW](https://www.raywenderlich.com/567-urlsession-tutorial-getting-started)